# $\mathbb{R}^2\otimes \mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I want to show $$\mathbb{R}^2\otimes \mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{C}^2.$$

My guess is to consider the map $f$ such that $(x,y)\otimes z\mapsto ((x,y),z)=(x+iy,z)=(\tilde{z},z)$ which is bijective. But I can't show that it preserves addition because I don't know how to make sense of $f((x,y)\otimes z+(x,y)'\otimes z')$.
Do we get linearity automatically from the universal property ? I am new to tensor products, so I am a bit confused about how things exactly work.

Comment: The map you defined is not even linear. Try to leverage the universal property to guess what to do

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification

Comment: Try $(x,y)\otimes z\mapsto (x,y)z$

Comment: @Filippo What do you mean by $(x,y)z$ ? Because I fail to see how is that an element of $\mathbb{C}^2$

Comment: @RyoikiTenkai $(x,y)z=(xz,yz)$

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2\otimes \mathbb{C}$ is a priori a real vector space, but it has an obvious complex structure and the function defined above is complex-linear. Moreover there are natural inclusions of $\mathbb R^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2\otimes \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}^2$ - in fact we are looking at two representations of the complexification of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and hence there is a unique natural isomorphism - namely the function defined above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general thing about tensor product, if you want to define linear map $f\colon A\otimes B\to C$, you first need to define bilinear map $g\colon A\times B\to C$, i.e. map that is linear in each argument separately. Then the universal property of tensor product guarantees that there is a unique linear map $f\colon A\otimes B\to C$ such that $f(a\otimes b) = g(a,b)$.

I'm not even sure what exactly is the map that you are trying to define, because equalities $((x,y),z) = (x+iy,z) = (\bar z,z)$ make zero sense, none of it is right.

The relevant general construction here is called [extension of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Extension_of_scalars). This works for modules, but in this context, we have some vector space $V$ over field $k$ and field $K\supseteq k$, and we want to define vector space $V^K$ over $K$ such that it extends addition and multiplication by scalars from $k$ on $V$. We do that by tensoring: $V^K:=K\otimes_k V$ where we define multiplication by scalars from $K$ by formula $\alpha\cdot(\beta\otimes v):=(\alpha\beta)\otimes v$. We can identify vectors from $V$ with vectors from $V^K$ of the form $1\otimes v$, for $v\in V$, and this defines $k$-linear embedding $v\mapsto 1\otimes v$ since for $\alpha \in k$ and $v\in V$ we have $\alpha v \mapsto 1\otimes \alpha v = \alpha\otimes v = \alpha\cdot(1\otimes v)$.

I've included this general construction since it should give you the correct idea what the factor $\mathbb C$ in $\mathbb R^2\otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$ does - it defines multiplication by complex numbers on $\mathbb R^2$. Therefore, any map $\mathbb R^2\otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C\to \mathbb C^2$ should take that in account, explicitly $(x,y)\otimes z$ should be mapped to $z\cdot (x,y)$ where $\cdot$ is multiplication by scalars in $\mathbb C^2$, i.e.  $z\cdot (x,y) = (zx,zy)$.

So, we define $\mathbb R$-bilinear map $\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb C\to \mathbb C^2$ by the formula $((x,y),z) \mapsto (zx,zy)$. You can verify that $$(\alpha_1(x_1,y_1)+\alpha_2(x_2,y_2),z)\mapsto \alpha_1(zx_1,zy_1)+\alpha_2(zx_2,zy_2)$$ and $$((x,y),\alpha_1z_1+\alpha_2z_2)\mapsto \alpha_1(z_1x,z_1y)+\alpha_2(z_2x,z_2y)$$ for all real $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,x,y,x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ and complex $z,z_1,z_2$.

By the universal property of tensor product, there is a unique $\mathbb R$-linear map $\mathbb R^2\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C\to \mathbb C^2$ that maps $(x,y)\otimes z$ to $(zx,zy)$. We still need to verify that the map is $\mathbb C$-linear, i.e. $z_1\cdot ((x,y)\otimes z_2)\mapsto z_1(z_2x,z_2y)$ but this is clear since $$z_1\cdot((x,y)\otimes z_2) = (x,y)\otimes (z_1z_2) \mapsto (z_1z_2x,z_1z_2y) = z_1(z_2x,z_2y).$$

What is left for you to do is to prove that this map is isomorphism.

Comment: "the universal property of tensor product guarantees that there is a unique linear map $:\otimes \to$
 such that $(\otimes )=(,)$". This may be be a stupid question but is $(\otimes + c\otimes d)=g(a,b)+g(c,d)? $ How we make sense of $(\otimes + c\otimes d)?$

Comment: @Ryoiki Tenkai, yes, that's what linearity tells you. This is similar to defining linear operator on a basis and extending to all vectors. Here it's bit more complicated since simple tensors $a\otimes b$ generate tensor product, but are not linearly independent, but tensor product is carefully defined as a particular quotient to avoid these issues.